# Inter-PVLAN communication on Arista 7050S

Tags: vlan, ip, subnet, ip-address, arista

We have an Arista 7050S configured with a few PVLANs. All hosts on these PVLAN share the same /24 network (major flaw?). They can communicate between themselves within each PVLAN and with the gateway (to be able to reach the Internet). They currently cannot communicate with each other, if the hosts are on different PVLANs.

There is a need to allow some servers from PVLAN 1 to access a service on a different host on PVLAN 2. Because they are on the same /24 network, that creates some issues.

We could fix the netmask but it would require some IP reassignments that we'd like to avoid. Are there are features on the eOS that we might be overlooking and would allow us to pierce some holes and permit inter-PVLAN communication with a /24 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all very basic networking that you must understand before you start designing networks.

If a host is trying to send to another host on the same network, it will not send to the router.  An IP address is the address for a layer-3 packet that gets encapsulated into a layer-2 frame before going out the layer-1 interface.

A layer-2 frame has source and destination addresses (MAC addresses), too.  The source host needs to know the destination layer-2 address so it looks in its ARP cache.  If it isn't in the ARP cache, it will ARP for it (a layer-2 broadcast).  Layer-2 broadcasts will not cross a layer-3 boundary (router) to get to another VLAN, so the sending host will never get the layer-2 address and can't send to the destination host.

That means that two hosts on separate VLANs, but in the same network, can't communicate at layer-2, so they can't communicate at layer-3.

If the two hosts are on different networks, the sending host uses the gateway's (router) layer-2 address to encapsulate the layer-3 packet.  The router will strip off the layer-2 frame and routes the layer-3 packet to another interface where it encapsulates the layer-3 packet into a new layer-2 frame.

What you really need is to use different networks for your different VLANs if you want them to communicate through the router.

Comment: Everything you said is very well understood (very basic network understanding) and I've not designed this network, I'm working with what has been given to me. There is nothing in your answer that wasn't explicitly mentioned in my question. I was curious as to if the switch would have a feature to workaround the current situation.

Comment: If you understand it then you understand that you need to either put them all on the same VLAN, or you need to put the VLANs on different networks. I'm not sure what you expect the switch to do; pretend that the VLANs don't exist?

Comment: I don't know, sir. Maybe there is a hidden feature that would allow this expensive L3 switch to act as a proxy for a service running on a given TCP port? Maybe something else entirely? I know the basics of networks and VLANs (as explained in my question where I mentioned how it was working, the issue with the improper netmask that is used, what would be necessary to it "properly", etc). I'm not asking about basic VLAN and TCP/IP concepts so your answer feels very condescending.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound condescending, but when you ask how to violate the basics of networking, I had to assume that you didn't understand them. One device on a network just can't talk to a device on the same network that is separated by a layer-3 boundary. They need to be on the same layer-2 network, it confuses the sending device which will never send the traffic to the gateway. They either need to be in the same layer-2 domain, or they need to be on different layer-3 networks.

Comment: No worries. It looks like we won't be able to pull any tricks with this switch (like the proxy situation I mentioned), which I was hoping would be the case since we've other more pressing issues. We'll investigate the real need to isolate these servers (since they're on the same /24, what was the original intention, right?) and maybe get away with the PVLAN (and use Arista's firewall to filter traffic from/to them) or carve a /28 out of the /24 and do some IP reassignments. The reality is the /24 address space is very scattared, which compicates things a bit. Thanks for your insights.